# Unable to export database as Excel from Filemaker

Tags: database, filemaker, data-extraction

Normally I should be able to go to File -> Export to export data from a Filemaker database. But the option does not appear for this database from a client.

[image: There is no Export option anywhere in the menus]

I wonder, is it a permissions issue, where the username they client provided does not have enough permissions to export? I've also tried opening it on Filemaker Pro Advanced Mac and Windows and on versions 18 and 19 and it works exactly the same way.

The file extension for the database is .fmp12 if that helps.

How can I export the database to Excel or CSV?

Comment: It appears that the file uses a custom menu set in which the Export Records menu item was excluded. Whether the privilege to export records has also been removed from the account's privilege set is not possible to determine from your screenshot.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know how I can verify that I have permission to export with the user/pass I was given?

Comment: Maybe, but it's rather complicated. If the file comes from your client, why don't you ask them to give you more privileges, or export the data for you? I am not comfortable advising you how to get data which the data owner may not want you to have.

Comment: OK I understand. I will ask the client for an admin username if they still have it.